# Sending ajax request gets an error

Tags: php, ajax, request

The following abstract of my code given:

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {

       var dataString = 'user=' + user + '&size=' + size + '&q_1=' + q_1 + '&q_2=' + q_2 + '&q_3=' + q_3 + '&q_4=' + q_4 + '&q_5=' + q_5;

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "form_send.php",    
           data: dataString,
           success: function() {
               //success
           },
           error: function() {
               //error
           }
       });

       return false;

   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST) {
$user = $_POST['user'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$q1 = $_POST['q_1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q_2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q_3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q_4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q_5'];

//insert data
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (username, size, q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5) VALUES ('$user', '$size', '$q1', '$q2', '$q3', '$q4', '$q5')");
if(!$insert){ die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());}

}
```

The other code is checked and working all right, so there has to be a mistake in this abstract; also I cannot find one.

Its always going into the "error" of the ajax request. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: FYI, the `data` property in the AJAX config also accepts an object. That's much easier than concatenating it manually.

Comment: use firebug and debug it by yourself...

Comment: And please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! @peterm: I will read those articles about MySQLi and PDO to learn the better way!

Comment: @JosephSilber: As also from albert mentioned I changed the data in ajax - thx!

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: You're right, I am very new to programming so maybe sometimes don't go the right way. I just used firebug and yes found the problem :) It was a n error 404 cause of the wrong path to ajax url, didn't check this :(

Comment: @impassem i am happy it helps :) lot of questions needs just simple debuging

Answer (score 0):

your data in ajax should like this

```
data:{'user' : user, 'size':size,'q_1' : q_1 , 'q_2':q_2, 'q_3': q_3 , 'q_4':q_4, 'q_5' :q_5}
```